# What is the difference between "@var ||= 123" and "return @var if defined?(@var); @var = 123"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-2.6

I'm using ruby 2.6.5 on my local machine. I also use the same ruby version on heroku machine.

However i got weird error on using heroku.

if i defined a method like:

```
def current_admin
  @current_admin ||= 'yana'
end
```

It works perfectly on my machine, on heroku it will raise a NameError:

```
NameError (`@` is not allowed as an instance variable name)
```

however when i do:

```
def current_admin
  return @current_admin if defined?(@current_admin)
  @current_admin = 'yana'
end
```

It works on both machine.

What exactly is the difference that cause first syntax fails on heroku?

*** Update ***

The diff i made to make it work on heroku.

```
   def current_account
-    @current_account ||= AccountSession.find
+    return @current_account if defined? @current_account
+
+    @current_account = AccountSession.find
   end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem possible. Exactly which line of code was the `NameError` on?

Comment: Once I had messed up with Zero-width space(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)
Try to clear @current_admin ||= 'yana' row completely and retype it again.

Comment: @Casper I probably messed up. The error was on `@current_admin ||= 'yana'`. I have edited the code to remove unnecessary context. However, I might be doing it wrong. I updated the question with the diff from the source code.

Comment: @SerhiiNadolynskyi thank you. That probably the problem. I have fixed it. I followed the coding style used in authlogic instead. However, how did you debug it so that you get into the conclusion that Zero-width space is the problem?

Comment: @YanaAgunSiswanto I do not remember how exactly I figured that out.
Probably I saw some difference in `git diff` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea about Heroku glitches, but here is the answer on what exactly is the difference.

```rb
@current_admin ||= 42
```

The line above is the exact equivalent of `@current_admin = @current_admin || 42`. That said, the value will be reset to `42` when `@current_admin` is `falsey`, aka _either `false` or `nil`.

`@defined` would reset the value if and only this instance variable *was not previously declared within current scope*. Even `nil` would stay as is if it was explicitly set before.

```rb
defined? @current_admin
#⇒ nil
@current_admin = nil
defined? @current_admin
#⇒ "instance-variable"
```